# close always one open element jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Tell me, please, now everything works fine, but one item remains open, close it?

http://jsfiddle.net/ktTKe/3/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var open = $('.open'),
            a = $('.location_cont').find('a.open');
         $(".item_in ul").customScrollbar({
            skin: "default-skin",
            hScroll: false,
        });
        open.on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this),
                speed = 300;
            if ($('.open').hasClass('active') === true) {
                $('.open').removeClass('active').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed);
            }
            if ($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
$this.removeClass('active').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
            } else if ($this.hasClass('active') === false) {
                $(".item_in ul").css("resize", true);
                $this.addClass('active').next('.item_in').slideDown(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
            } else {
                $this.removeClass('active').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed);
                $this.addClass('active').next('.item_in').delay(speed).slideDown(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remove the `active` class when you slide up so you can check to see if it if the current element that was clicked.

```
open.on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        speed = 300;
    if ($('.open').hasClass('active') === true) {
        $('.open').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed);
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
        $this.removeClass('active').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
    } else {
        $(".item_in ul").css("resize", true);
        $('.open').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active').next('.item_in').slideDown(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ktTKe/4/

Answer (score 1):

i have modified in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Vym2M/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var open = $('.open'),
        a = $('.location_cont').find('a.open');
     $(".item_in ul").customScrollbar({
        skin: "default-skin",
        hScroll: false,
    });
    open.on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var speed = 300;
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') === true) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('active') === false) {
            $(".item_in ul").css("resize", true);
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.item_in').slideDown(speed).find('ul').customScrollbar("resize", true);
        }
    });
});
```

cancel

```
    if ($('.open').hasClass('active') === true) {
        $('.open').removeClass('active').next('.item_in').slideUp(speed);
    }
```

and use $(this) instead variable $this.

remove also the last else because isn't necessary

Comment: Unfortunately it is not quite that, but anyway, thank you for some help!

Comment: ok do you want only one open div. i suggest you look at accordion ui. It could be usefull http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I'm not good with English, probably on this we do not understand each other ( That's what I wanted http://jsfiddle.net/ktTKe/4/ forgive me)